# Stata. How to transform a dataset into pure panel data?

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have done this many times with Excel and Java... This time I need to do it using Stata because it is more convenient to preserve variables' `labels`. How can I restructure dataset_1 into dataset_2 below?

**I need to transform the following dataset_1:**

[image]

**into dataset_2:**

[image]

I know one way, which is a little awkward... I mean, I could `expand` all the observations, then create variable `obsNo`, and then, `rename` variables...is there any better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stata is wonderful at this sort of thing, it's a simple `reshape`. Your data is a little awkward, as the `reshape` command was designed to work with variables where the common part of the variable name (in your case, Wage) comes first. In the documentation for `reshape`, "Wage" would be the stub. The part following Wage is required to be numeric. If you first sort your variable names by

```
rename (raceWhiteWage raceBlackWage raceAsianWage) (Wage1 Wage2 Wage3)
```

Then you can do:

```
reshape long Wage, i(state year) j(race)
```

That should give you the output your are looking for. You will have a column labeled "race", with values of 1 for White, 2 for Black, and 3 for Asian.

Comment: Reshape is a tricky command, I cannot even grasp it yet. The suffix of the stub, Wage, needs to be numeric. I'll edit my answer now

Comment: @Snoozer You can have string suffixes; you just need to make that explicit with the `string` option.